# Prove the improper integral of the Gamma function $\Gamma(t)$ converges for $z \in \mathbb C$ with $Re(z) > 0$:

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove the improper integral of the Gamma function  $\Gamma(t)$ converges for $z \in \mathbb C$ with $Re(z) > 0$:
The gamma function $\Gamma(t)$ is defined by the following improper integral $$\Gamma(t) = \int^{\infty}_0 x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$$

It is said that the integral converges for $z \in \mathbb C$ with $Re(z) >0$, and I've been trying to find a way of proving this.

Using integration by parts we know $\Gamma(t+1) = t\Gamma(t)$. However this doesn't really prove anything does it ? Because here we assume the improper definite integral converges (correct me if I'm wrong). Also if $t$ is not a positive integer, but some positive real number, we must evaluate $\Gamma(t)$ for some $t \in (0,1)$.

Could someone tell me how to determine that this integral actually converges ?

Comment: First, for complex $z$, take the modulus of the integrand. Since $\lvert x^{z-1}\rvert = x^{\operatorname{Re} z - 1}$ for $x > 0$, that takes you to the real case, and all you need to show is $$\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx < \infty$$ for $t > 0$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am new here and have no permission to add the following comment to the discussion below for proving:
$x^{t-1}e^{-x}\leq e^{-x/2}$, where $x\geq 1$.
As stated in the question, we can assume wlog that $t\in[0,1]$.
Then the claim trivially holds since $x^{t-1}\leq x^0=1$.

Answer (score 21):

Hints using the comment of Daniel:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx=\int\limits_0^1 x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx+\int\limits_1^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$$

Now, we have that

$$0\le x\le 1\;\implies\;\; x^{t-1}e^{-x}\le x^{t-1}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\int\limits_0^1x^{t-1}dx=\left.\frac{x^t}t\right|_0^1=\frac1t$$

and we also have that

$$1\le x\;\implies\;\;x^{t-1}e^{-x}\stackrel{\text{Prove this!}}\le e^{-x/2}\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;\int\limits_1^\infty e^{-x/2}dx=\left.-2e^{-x/2}\right|_1^\infty=2 e^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Thanks DonAntonio. Just because we can compute an upper bound for the improper integral $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{t-1}e^{-x} dx$ using the function $e^{-x/2}$, why does this imply that the integral $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{t-1}e^{-x} dx$ actually converges ? I mean, just because we have an upper bound why does the limit that the integral corresponds to neccesarily converges ?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, review the tests for convergence of improper integrals of non-negative functions.

Comment: You are missing a constant (depending on $t$) in the estimate for $x \geqslant 1$. At the moment, you say that $\Gamma(t)$ remains bounded for $t\to \infty$. (Nevertheless, +1, I trust you will fix the omission.)

Comment: Well, yes, though the constant thing *already* proves convergence and not only that the function *remains bounded*, since $\;\int\limits_1^N x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx\;$ clearly exists as usual Riemann integral. Anyway:$$x^{t-1}e^{-x}\le e^{-x/2}\iff x^{t-1}\le e^{x/2}$$ and the last equality is true for $\;x\;$ big enough as $\;\frac{e^{x/2}}{x^{t-1}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}\infty\;$ (for example, l'Hospital until $\;t-k<0\;$ ...)

Comment: Hi DonAntonio. I've been trying to prove $x^{t-1}e^{-x} \le e^{-x/2}$.

I know $$e^{-x} \le e^{-1/4x} \ \ 1 \le x$$. However $$x^{t-1} \ge e^{-1/4x}$$ if $t = 2 \land x = 1$. So I cannot multiply to get the proper inequality.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen, try the following  argument (note the double implications!):$$x^{t-1}e^{-x}\le x^{-x/2}\iff x^{t-1}\le e^{x/2}\iff \frac{x^{t-1}}{e^{x/2}}\le 1$$ and the last inequality is true for $\;x\;$ big enough since $\;\frac{x^{t-1}}{e^{x/2}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0\;$ (use l'Hospital, for example)

Comment: But this is not true ? What if $t=10$ and $x=2$ then $2^{10} / e \ge 1$. I need this to be true for every $x \in [0;\infty)$ not just true assymptotically ?

Comment: No, of course not @NicolasLykkeIversen: it is enough that it is true for all $\;x\ge N\;$ ,since then you can split the integral $$\int\limits_1^\infty=\int\limits_1^N+\int\limits_N^\infty$$

Comment: So when you say $1\le x\;\implies\;\;x^{t-1}e^{-x}\stackrel{\text{Prove this!}}\le e^{-x/2}$, you really mean for some big enough $N$, $$N\le x\;\implies\;\;x^{t-1}e^{-x}\stackrel{\text{Prove this!}}\le e^{-x/2}$$  don't you?

Comment: @Jack Yes. Observe the inequality is equivalent with $\;e^{x/2}\ge x^{t-1}\;$ , which is clearly true for all values of $\;x\;$ big enough, as exponential kills polynomial (you can prove this directly with limits, say using L'Hospital)